# Usage of Conditional statements in React to change the color of table row based on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

The product has {name,price,quantity}.As per the quantity, change the product row to blue if quantity <10,to red if quantity=0 and normal if quantity >0.

```
function ProductRow(props){
  
    const product = props.product;
    const name = product.stocked && product.quantity===0 ?
    product.name :
    <span style={{color: 'red'}}>
      {product.name}
    </span>;
  const quantity = product.quantity>10 ?
  product.quantity :
  <span style={{color: 'blue'}}>
    {product.quantity}
</span>; 
       
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{product.price}</td>
        <td>{quantity}</td> 
      </tr>
    );
  
}

export default ProductRow;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd make a function that, given quantity, calculates the color, then style the `<tr>` with the result:

```
const getColor = (quantity) => {
    if (quantity === 0) return 'red';
    if (quantity < 10) return 'blue';
    return '';
};
function ProductRow({ product }) {
    return (
        <tr style={{ color: getColor(product.quantity) }}>
            <td>{product.name}</td>
            <td>{product.price}</td>
            <td>{product.quantity}</td>
        </tr>
    );
}
```

Comment: But for quantity=0,the row is not changing to red.It's changing to blue too.

Comment: If `quantity` is indeed a number, and the number is 0, it should change to red. Make sure that `quantity` contains the sort of data you're expecting. If it's a string instead, for example, you'll have to cast it to a number first.

Comment: Yes. `quantity` is number and it has 0.But I think because 0 is also <10,it's changing to blue.

Comment: That isn't possible. The first `return` will terminate the function with a return value of `'red'` in such a case. Something else is going on.

Comment: So, I removed one `=` just to see, and it worked. But as per syntax `===` is correct way.But at the end the output is correct.I need to figure this out.

Comment: @NPam If `==` works but `===` doesn't, then your `quantity` is definitely a string, not a number.

Comment: Yes,I made a mistake .Got it now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're changing the color of only a particular column is that you are creating a colored span based on your props and rendering it inside your table, which is only a column. The best approach would be to create classes in CSS and then conditionally assign those classes to an entire row.

```
.small{
  color:red;
}
.large{
  color:blue;
}
```

Feel free to change the CSS or the classnames as desired. Now inside your component-

```
 const product = props.product;
 const quantity=product.quanity;
 const quantityClass=product.quanity==0? 'small' ? product.quanity<=10 ? 'large' : '';
```

Assign the `quantityClass` classname to your row

```
 <tr className={quantityClass}>
            <td>{product.name}</td>
            <td>{product.price}</td>
            <td>{product.quantity}</td>
        </tr>
```